# SSRS Parameter Passing Issue

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdl

We're using SSRS within an application where users login and are authenticated based on their Store.  When they generate reports, we pass their store name to SSRS to generate report for their store. Everything works fine on the first report generation.  But when the user picks a different date range, they get report for all of the stores in the system.  We use MDX to feed the default and available parameter for store name in the .rdl as follows:

```sql
SELECT
   NON EMPTY { [Measures].[MTDActiveMembers],
   [Measures].[YTDActiveMembers],
   [Measures].[MTDMembers],
   [Measures].[YTDMembers],
   [Measures].[Members],
   [Measures].[Members - Active] } 
   ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY { ([Store].[Store].[Store].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,
   MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
   ON ROWS 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
( STRTOSET(@StoreStore, CONSTRAINED) ) 
         ON COLUMNS 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
( STRTOMEMBER(@FromCalendarDateHierarchy, CONSTRAINED) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToCalendarDateHierarchy, CONSTRAINED) ) 
               ON COLUMNS 
            FROM
               [Members]
         )
   )
   CELL PROPERTIES VALUE,
   BACK_COLOR,
   FORE_COLOR,
   FORMATTED_VALUE,
   FORMAT_STRING,
   FONT_NAME,
   FONT_SIZE,
   FONT_FLAGS
```

Stepping through the app revealed that when the user picks a different date range, all the parameters are intact, correct store name is preserved, but when the user hits "View Report" parameter for store name changes to ALL.  :w00t:  What could be wrong?  As far as app is concerned "View Report" is a black box, so don't know what to change with the rdl :(  Thanks in advance for your input.

**Edited**
Sorry, the query I provided above is the actual report query.  Parameter query is this:

```sql
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Store].[Store].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Store].[Store].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Store].[Store].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
SELECT
   {[Measures].[ParameterCaption],
   [Measures].[ParameterValue],
   [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} 
   ON COLUMNS,
   [Store].[Store].ALLMEMBERS 
   ON ROWS 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
( STRTOMEMBER(@FromCalendarDateHierarchy, CONSTRAINED) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToCalendarDateHierarchy, CONSTRAINED) ) 
         ON COLUMNS 
      FROM
         [Members]
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Instead of returning really all members you need to change following line :

```
 NON EMPTY { ([Store].[Store].[Store].ALLMEMBERS ) }
```

To:

```
 NON EMPTY { [Store].[Store].[Store] }
```

It will return to you only those which have values.

Comment: I think it's due to default parameters set.  Once I removed defaults it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that when the Date is modified all the parameters below this are updated, you must check if the `Store parameter` is **below** the `Date parameter`:
[image]

Move the `Store` parameter above the `Date` with the arrow **Up**
[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: I think it's also due to the defaults set on the parameters.